# Why doesn't the border extend to the bottom of the popup of my chrome extension?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension, sass

I'm programming a chrome extension and styling its popup using Bootstrap 5 e Sass, but the border of the popup does not extend to the bottom. What could be causing this?

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/popup.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <button id="startBtn" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="display: inline;">Connect</button>
        <button id="createRoomBtn" class="btn btn-primary" style="display: none;">Create Room</button>
        <button id="enterRoomBtn" class="btn btn-secondary" style="display: none;">Enter Room</button>
    </div>
    <script src="./popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.scss**

```
$primary: rebeccapurple;
$secondary: #77216F;
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

html
{
    //Reset    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;

    width: 276px;
    height: 376px;
    border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 15%;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #212121;
    color: white;
}
```

Image of what is happening:

[image: Image of what is happening]

I tried reseting some css properties, tried moving the border declaration to the body and a wrapper div, tried with zero margin and nothing worked.

Comment: Add an [MCVE](/help/mcve) to your question using the "snippet" button.

Comment: I wonder if it's `margin-top` causing the issue.

Comment: @Ouroborus I've tried removing it but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out that, indeed, what was causing the border to not extend was the margin. However, when I tried removing it, it didn't work, so I changed it to `padding`and the border behaved normally.